# Visual Studio 2013 setup doesn't run

Tags: visual-studio-2013, installation

I'm trying to install Visual Studio 2013 and when I click the autorun.exe to install the 'Visual Studio' logo just shows up and then disappears and it doesn't take me to the setup. The same happens with VS 2012 and with the web installers.

I was having other problems with VS before(couldn't install or unnistall, but that is solved. Tried to unnistall it with Revo Unnistaller and at the end it said run32dll was not working)